# How to do a simple 'model fitting' in python?

Tags: python, model-fitting

Suppose I have three data sets `x, y, z`.

I want to fit a simple model: `A*x + B*y + C = z` (A, B, C are constant.)

How can I do that in Python?

I've found `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. However, it seems like it can take only one variable: `curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata[, p0, sigma])`, which fits `f(x) = y`. What I need is `f(x, y)=z`.

In Mathematica, `NonLinearModelFit` can do the job. I am wondering whether there is a similar module in Python that I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) suggest that `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` can indeed do what you need. In particular:

> xdata : An M-length sequence or an (k,M)-shaped array
>
> > for functions with k predictors. The independent variable where the data is measured.
>
> ydata : M-length sequence
>
> > The dependent data — nominally f(xdata, ...)

If your independent variables are currently individual arrays, you could combine them with [np.vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack):

```
scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, np.vstack(x, y), z)
```

Comment: I misunderstood the description of `xdata` in the docs. I will be more careful next time. Sometimes, I wish my mother tongue is English...  Thank you very much!